# UIView Loaded From Nib Appears Wrongly Scaled Intermittently

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

So we've just released an iOS app that makes heavy use of loading views from Nibs (use of Nib's may or may not be related).

On all my own test devices, everything works as expected, however some users are reporting UI that's scaled disproportionally to their device.

By way of example, here is what the screen should look like:

[Correctly Proportioned Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOAqU.png) vs [Erroneous Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANJ1h.jpg)

Both screenshots were taken on an iPhone 6s, running iOS 11.4, and both using the same version of the app.

The code to load the nib is fairly straightforward:

```
extension UINib {
    static func instantiateViewAndEmbedWithConstraints <T: UIView> (viewType: T.Type, embedInto containerView: UIView) -> T {
        let view = UINib(nibName: String(describing: viewType), bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! T
        containerView.addSubview(view)

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let leadingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        leadingConstraint.identifier = "leading"

        leadingConstraint.isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

        return view
    }    
}
```

I'm somewhat bewildered... Everything has the same auto-layout constraints in place, so there's no logical reason I can think of for it to be resizing views like this.

It uses auto-layout, buttons are a set height / leading / trailing across all devices... But for some users everything is just being scaled up.

Anyway, I was just hoping someone on here might have even an inkling of what might be the root cause that I could try delve into; as I'm drawing a blank / have just been banging my head against a wall the entire day!

Many thanks.

Comment: Your "correct" screen-shot is `750 x 1334` while your "erroneous" image is `640 x 1136`. Are you *sure* they are both from `iPhone 6s`?

Comment: Also, check if one device has the display set to `zoomed`.

Comment: As @DonMag suggested, turn on large text on your device and see if something weird happens.